# Postfix 'mydestination' empty entry/floating comma

Tags: email, postfix

Postfix setting 'mydestination' has a floating comma by default, which I assume means an empty entry to the list.

[Documentation](https://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html) doesn't mention this. Examples are given under the header *"What domains to receive mail for"*. The default setting of /etc/postfix/main.cf is:

```
...
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, localhost.com, , localhost
...
```

What is the function of this comma/empty entry?

Comment: it would be nice if you posted more informations about your system and version of postfix ... etc ....

Comment: Running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS with the latest version of Postfix, v3.7.2. I've updated recently after a year or so and seem to recall it being the same back then. I don't suspect this to be version bound

Comment: I'm also not experiencing any noticeable difference with vs without this comma. Everything (web/mail) works just fine either way. This is very much based on UX and not on clever data, though.